# Solve Compound Inequality Without Separation With Variables on Outside

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following compound inequality:

$3y-5 < -2y < 2+y$

I know I can separate them into two different equations, and go from there. I have been taught how to solve them without separation when the variable is in the center. But I have not been taught how to do this when there are variables on the outside like this one? How do you I "put the y variable back into the center?

The way I see it, I  can't do it. I can -y from both sides and add it to the center, but still leaves a 2y on the left. I can -3y and add it to the center, but that leaves a -2y on the right. The only way to solve it is through separation. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Compound inequalities are just single inequalities that must be simultaneously true.  In other words, $$3y - 5 < -2y < 2 + y$$ is just a more compact way of saying $$3y - 5 < -2y \quad {\it and} \quad -2y < 2 + y.$$  Then you solve the individual inequalities:

$$3y - 5 < -2y$$ implies $$5y < 5$$ which is equivalent to $$y < 1.$$  The second inequality is $$3y > -2$$ or $$y > -\frac{2}{3}.$$  Now you put them back together; we must simultaneously have $y < 1$ and $y > -\frac{2}{3}$, or $$-\frac{2}{3} < y < 1.$$

I believe this process is what you call "separation."  I do not advise trying any other shortcut method that involves working both inequalities at the same time.  It's not that it can't be done, it's that it's potentially confusing and you may make a mistake, especially as the inequalities become more complicated.  Even in this case, you can see that there is no way to algebraically add or subtract any multiple of $y$ to both inequalities simultaneously in order to eliminate $y$ from the extremes.  This is because the the LHS inequality $3y - 5 < -2y$ leads to the RHS inequality $y < 1$, and vice versa.  The "ends" become the "middle."

Comment: @visualbread On the one hand, this answer ducks your question re "I have been taught how to solve them without separation when the variable is in the center."  On the other hand, heropup had **very good** reason.  As I see it, there are two possibilities: [1] whoever taught you how to solve specific compound inequalities without separation never intended that priority should be given to avoiding separation.  Plausibly, they wanted merely to expand your intuition to the possibility of finding inequalities like $a < b < c$, which has a format similar to $a = b = c.$ ...see next comment

Comment: [2] If I have misread the intent re giving priority to avoiding separation, then, in my opinion, your teacher **went off the rails**, for the very reasons given by heropup in his answer.

Comment: heropup's explanation seems to suggest that it is better in the long run to separate them out, then solve them. I'm absolutely comfortable sticking to that habit if that's the better habit to be in.

Answer (score 0):

$$3y-5 < -2y < 2+y\implies 2y-5 \lt -3y \lt 2$$

$$2y-5 \lt -3y\implies 5y\lt 5\implies y \lt 1 
\quad \land \quad  
-3y \lt 2\implies -2 \lt 3y\implies -\frac{2}{3} \lt y$$

$$\therefore -\frac{2}{3} \lt y \lt 1$$